# Is there a way to spellcheck the word under the cursor with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spellcheck

Basically, is there any way to trigger the native OS X spellcheck context menu using a keyboard shortcut. I know the command keys <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> activates spellcheck, but what I'm trying to do is get the result of a right-click without taking my hands off the keyboard. Is there an OS X equivalent to emacs' flyspell-correct-word-before-point command.

Comment: I don't know of a way to get spellcheck, but pressing Control-Command-D will show you the definition of the word under the cursor or by the insertion point. If you don't get a result, then your word is most likely misspelled (it doesn't provide hints though).

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Lion, you can turn on iOS-style spelling corrections in *System Preferences* under *Language and Text*. I don't always have luck noticing or reacting to these corrections while typing, but moving back over the misspelled word with your cursor will bring up the iOS-style popup and you can select the correct spelling with the down arrow and Return.

A similar question was asked on superuser, see [Keyboard Shortcut to Right Click](https://superuser.com/questions/93937/keyboard-shortcut-to-right-click-in-mac-os-x). To paraphrase that answer here:

- Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> to activate spellcheck
- Focus the floating window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd>. (You need "Full Keyboard Access" shortcuts enabled in *System Preferences*. And unfortunately for me while typing this, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> is already used by the Stack Exchange editor.)
- Use Tab and Arrows to navigate and select the right spelling
- Use Escape to dismiss the floating window

You can also "Activate Mouse Keys", but I find that solution unsatisfying.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone makes this so complicated! all you have to do is click and hold control and command and the click the word. and the suggestion words pop up

Comment: Did you read the question?  He wants a way to do it without the need to click.