# Shortcut for right click on underlined misspelled words

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

As many I tend to misspell some words when I type. OS X is being nice and underlines them letting me know that something was not right, if use a mouse and right click on the underlined word a menu pops up and offers the correct spelling of this word.

Is there a way to trigger this menu from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of, but not quite in the same way - without the mouse to indicate which word you mean, it has to start from the top & work through them all...

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>:</kbd>  will pop up the full spell-checker with which you can then navigate through the doubtful words, but once open, you need to interact with it using the mouse, even to actually make it the front-most window.

[image]

Comment: actually this is great, you can interface with it using the keyboard, using arrows to get to the spelling that you are looking for, `enter` to correct the word and `Cmd ⌘` + `W` to close the pop up window, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try <kbd>Cmd:</kbd> (colon), that's not exactly the same menu but it may do what you're looking for.

Source :
[Is there a way to spellcheck the word under the cursor with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39765/is-there-a-way-to-spellcheck-the-word-under-the-cursor-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)